# python: best way to keep db open / or reconect

Tags: python

i have a python script that its always on runing on background

**nohup python script.py &**

so what script does is: it check on mqtt if any message there and if true it insert it on Database

```
on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    SQL.execute("INSERT INTO logs(deviceID) VALUES (msg)")
```

i use this way to connect to db but after few hours connection is closed and script is running but its not able to insert to db

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",  user="xxxx",  passwd="xxxx",  database="xxx")
SQL = mydb.cursor()
```

**Questions:**

1. do i need to open new connection every time before **SQL.execute()** or better to keep it open?
2. can u add code that u think is better to use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [single database connection throughout the python application (following singleton pattern)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525545/single-database-connection-throughout-the-python-application-following-singleto)

Comment: i think my question can be answered by someone just with 2 wordsand what code should i use

Comment: @wuqnyqow do see my answer let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

How frequent are your messages?  If they aren’t too frequent, I’d just `try`  open the connection, insert, then close it in an `else`.  Connection are system resources, you should not waste them.

Also, some database engines, no idea about mysql, will periodically garbage-collect long-idle connections and your connection will, unexpectedly, be closed when you attempt using it.

```
on_message(client, userdata, msg):

    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",  user="xxxx",  passwd="xxxx",  database="xxx")
        SQL = mydb.cursor()
        #☝️ use mysqls parametrized queries
        SQL.execute("INSERT INTO logs(deviceID) VALUES (%s)", (msg,))
    except Exception as e:
        raise
    else:
        SQL.close()
```

Comment: sometimes 1 hour no msg , but sometimes 1 msg per second. but python script should run in background all the time(1 year :P)

Comment: I’d put the connection open code in a function elsewhere though, esp because of password.  Disclaimer: on tablet, so typos are possible on my end.

Comment: If a stand alone script w 1 yr uptime reqs I’d get the script working first, then make it into a daemon/service with by launching with a specialized program that keeps it up always : systemd, runit or monit might be good choices on a Linux system for example.  runit runs on almost any POSIX.  They’re a pain to deal with but steady long uptimes require them.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runit

Comment: Also, your db could be down for a little while - say maintenance - so on intermittent connection errors I’d append the msg into a list and try writing it next time. Or drop it if that’s OK.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to open the connection when you need it and not simply leave it open as that will waste a ton of resources.

You can add a decorator to any db handler function like this to reconnect MySQL db when exception 'MySQL server has gone away' raised. Code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440055/correct-way-of-keeping-mysql-connection)

```
class DB:
    """Database interface"""

    def retry(func):
        def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
            lock.acquire()
            try:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                if 'MySQL server has gone away' in str(e):
                    # reconnect MySQL
                    self.connect_mysql()
                else:
                    # No need to retry for other reasons
                    pass
            finally:
                lock.release()
        return call

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def connect_mysql(self):
        # create connection here

    @retry
    def execute(self):
        # use the decorator to get conenction and do you SQL.execute() here
```